# jQuery update data not working

Tags: jquery

I was looking around the web, but is look like I can not resolve my problem.

I can not updata data-value.

this is the anchor code where I have data

```
<a href="/channel/watch/HotIce" class="advance-hovercard user" data-toggle="popover" data-id="47" data-isfollowing="1">Name</a>
```

now i need to update data-follower

I tryed with:

```
$('.advance-hovercard[data-id="'+id+'"]').attr('data-isfollowing', 0);
```

and with:

```
$('.advance-hovercard[data-id="'+id+'"]').data('isfollowing', 0);
```

no one work for me. Then I tryed a test with:

```
$('.advance-hovercard[data-id="'+id+'"]').css({'background-color':'red'});
```

and this working, the code take the anchor but not change data-isfollowing.

where i am wrong?

Comment: it's working fine. Just run that statement inside document.ready event handler. http://jsbin.com/vucuxu/1/edit?html,css,js,console,output

Comment: is it after document ready.

Comment: Inside document.ready event handler. Like this `$(function() {
  $('.advance-hovercard[data-id="47"]').attr('data-isfollowing', 0);
});`

Comment: Thanks, i resolved, the problem was undefined variable isFollowing, i changed from `$(this).attr('data-isfollowing');`  to `$('.advance-hovercard[data-id="'+id+'"]').attr('data-isfollowing');`  and now working :)

Comment: Great. but `$(this)` was not mentioned anywhere in the question ;)

Comment: yes that's true but i was not image was there the problem